# How does Ruby pass array's element to variables directly?

Tags: ruby

In:

```
controller_name, action = "page", "action"
```

each object on the right assigns to the variables on the left.

In this code:

```
controller_name, action = "page/action".split("/")
```

the result is the same. Probably it's a stupid question but I want to know how Ruby does it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`"page/action".split("/")` creates an **array** in Ruby.

Then `controller_name, action = "page/action".split("/")` it causes the parallel assignment, by **splatting** the array, created by [`String#split`](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-2.1.0/String.html#method-i-split) method.

Below are all the intermediate steps handled/taken by Ruby itself for you :

```
controller_name, action = "page/action".split("/")
             ↓
controller_name, action = ['page','action'] # <- intermediate
             ↓
controller_name, action = *['page','action'] # <- intermediate
             ↓
controller_name, action = 'page','action' # final assignment happened now.
```

Read the [`Parallel Assignment`](http://ruby-doc.com/docs/ProgrammingRuby/html/tut_expressions.html#UC)

> You can *collapse* and *expand* arrays using Ruby's *parallel assignment operator*. If the last lvalue is preceded by an asterisk, all the remaining rvalues will be collected and assigned to that lvalue as an array. Similarly, if the last rvalue is an array, you can prefix it with an asterisk, which effectively expands it into its constituent values in place. (This is not necessary if the rvalue is the only thing on the right-hand side---the array will be expanded automatically.)